# catplot doesn´t display bars while importing a csv

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, catplot, countplot

I have made my own code trying to find any differences but I don´t know where is the trick, here is one catplot that display well:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Change the color palette to "RdBu"
par_ad = {
    "Parents advice":[1,2,3,3,4,5,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5,2,1,3,4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(par_ad)
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_palette("RdBu")


# Create a count plot of survey responses
sns.catplot(x="Parents advice", 
            data=df, 
            kind="count")

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

On the other hand I have been working with a .csv and using orders inside it. Why it doesn´t show the bars? The code, the .csv belongs to a Datacamp course about Seaborn, it doesn´t throw any error apart from not displaying the bars.
First line in .csv is the categories, where one of them is "Parents' advice" and the other lines are ints between 1 to 5 that are equivalent to the number of times where students ask for help from their parents.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Change the color palette to "RdBu"
survey_data = pd.read_csv("young-people-survey-responses.csv")
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_palette("RdBu")

# Create a count plot of survey responses
category_order = ["Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", 
                  "Often", "Always"]

sns.catplot(x="Parents' advice", 
            data=survey_data, 
            kind="count", 
            order=category_order)

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

How is `sns` supposed to know that `"Never"` equals `1`, `"Rarely"` equals `2`, and so on?

**Option 1**

- Pass `range(1,6)` to the `order` parameter and use [`ax.set_xticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) to overwrite the range values.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# using the values from your initial example
par_ad = {"Parents' advice": [1,2,3,3,4,5,4,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5,2,1,3,4]}
survey_data = pd.DataFrame(par_ad)

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.set_palette("RdBu")

category_order = ["Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", 
                  "Often", "Always"]

ax = sns.catplot(x="Parents' advice", 
                 data=survey_data, 
                 kind="count", 
                 order=range(1,6)) # set order: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

# adjust the labels
ax.set_xticklabels(category_order)

plt.show()
```

**Result**:

[image: catplot]

**Option 2**

- Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to change the range values into your string values and make the column categorical using [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) before passing it to [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html).

```
# ...

category_order = ["Never", "Rarely", "Sometimes", 
                  "Often", "Always"]

# create a dict to map cats to unique values in the `"Parents' acvice"` column, dropping any nan values
unique_advice = sorted(survey_data["Parents' advice"].dropna().unique())
mapper = dict(zip(unique_advice, category_order))

# make column categorical 
survey_data["Parents' advice"] = (pd.Categorical(survey_data["Parents' advice"]
                                                 .map(mapper), 
                                                 categories=category_order))

ax = sns.catplot(x="Parents' advice", 
                 data=survey_data, 
                 kind="count") # `order` no longer needed

plt.show()
# same result
```